# Writing Test classes to get code into production

Tags: apex, deployment

I picked up this trigger code yesterday and it works perfectly:

```
trigger OpportunityAutoUpdate on Opportunity (before insert)
{
   // get the ids of all the accounts
     Set<Id> accIds=new Set<Id>();
   for (Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
 {
     accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
 }

   // retrieve the accounts and owners
  List<Account> accs=[select id, OwnerId from Account where id in :accIds];
  Map<Id, Account> accById=new Map<Id, Account>();
  accById.putall(accs);

   // iterate the opportunities, updating the opportunity owner to the account owner
   for (Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
  {
       // any logic about when to do this - i.e. only if the current owner matches a
       // particular id goes here
      if (null!=opp.AccountId)
       {
          opp.OwnerId=accById.get(opp.AccountId).OwnerId;
       }  }
}
```

I can not get it into our production Org as we only have 73% coverage.

Any ideas for writing a test class to help get this in?

Update: I found a way to get it in, how do I change the code so it only works if the opportunity owner if a Picklist value is selected?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=apex+unit+tests

Comment: Hello Alexander, we need to understand what have you tried already and if you are facing any issues with it? Can you please let us know if you tried writing a test class? If not you should atleast write that first and then if you are still facing issues with the coverage we can probably try to help you.

Comment: I would suggest you do some reading on Apex testing and TDD
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_intro.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @isTest 
private class testforAccount 
{    
static testMethod void unittest()    
{
              Account objAccount = new Account(Name = 'Test');
              insert objAccount;

              Opportunity objOpp = new Opportunity(Name='TestOppt', CloseDate=Date.today(), StageName='Open',  AccountId =objAccount.Id)
              insert objOpp;    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split out the first and last loops in your trigger into separate methods and write tests for those

- one for the loop that builds the list of Ids given a list of SObjects,
- one that takes a list of opportunities and a map of Id, Account and sets the owner Id, per your second loop.

Note: you can create the map accById like this

```
Map<Id, Account> accById = new Map<Id, Account>(accs);
```

thus eliminating the .putAll() call.

By the time you've done that, your trigger itself will be just four lines long, your unit test coverage will be a lot higher and and you will have some reusable code as a bonus.

Comment: You can even do this directly from your SOQL Statement:
`Map<Id,Account> accById = new Map<Id,Account>([select id, OwnerId from Account where id in :accIds]);`
See here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_map_sobject.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_map_sobject.htm|SkinName=webhelp[link]